# Calculate time different between two columns using R

Tags: r

I have a .csv file uploaded on R and I need to calculate the duration of the given date/time stamp. Here is my raw data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  started_at = c("2022/01/13 11:59", "2022/01/10 8:41", "2022/01/25 4:53", "2022/01/04 0:18"),
  ended_at = c("2022/01/13 12:02", "2022/01/10 8:46", "2022/01/25 4:58", "2022/01/04 0:33")
)
```

I tried difftime but that was when I tried to separate the date and the time before uploading it to R and yet it didn't give me a new column on the table to use in a further analysis. I would want a result to concat the date and time for the two columns and be able to calculate time difference by adding new columns on the .csv file so I can view it anytime I need to.

Comment: data$diff_time = difftime(data$started_at,data$ended_at)?

Comment: I have tried this and it gives me an error about "POSIXCT string not standard unambiguous format" as  I have split column the date and the time so I can calculate the difference between two column  like this ----------trips_2022$date_start <- as.Date(trips_2022$started_at)
trips_2022$time_start <- format(as.POSIXct(trips_2022$started_at),format = "%H:%M:%S")
trips_2022$date_ended <- as.Date(trips_2022$ended_at)
trips_2022$time_ended <- format(as.POSIXct(trips_2022$ended_at),format = "%H:%M:%S")
View(trips_2022)

Answer (score 0):

I created a dataframe using the information you supplied and converted it into datetime format with `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  started_at = c("2022/01/13 11:59", "2022/01/10 8:41", "2022/01/25 4:53", "2022/01/04 0:18"),
  ended_at = c("2022/01/13 12:02", "2022/01/10 8:46", "2022/01/25 4:58", "2022/01/04 0:33")
) %>% mutate(
    started_at = ymd_hm(started_at),
    ended_at = ymd_hm(ended_at))
```

Then you can use `mutate` to create a new column that is the difference in time between the start time and end time.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(time_diff = ended_at - started_at)
```

Comment: got it now, thanks guys for your help, I tried both suggestions and I figured out that I dont actually need to split the date and the time to calculate the trip duration. I just got the idea of splitting by working on this first in excel..

Comment: Maybe you can post the solution for your question?